How to I multiply two small matrices, with a Gaudi accelerator?
Intel's Gaudi line of accelerators seems to target CNN simulations and related framework(s) such as Pytorch etc. But - with the release of Gaudi 3 - I want to have an idea of whether, and how, I can use it more generally. For that purpuse, I would like to see a small "hello world"-level program using it.
So, suppose I have two small matrices A and B in (system) memory, and I want to use a Gaudi accelerator to multiply them. If it were an AMD or an NVIDIA card, I would know how to do that using OpenCL, or for the NVIDIA case, using their warp matrix-multiply-add functions (as described here). My question is: How do I do this with Gaudi?
Notes:

Assume I have installed all of the relevant drivers, compilers, libraries and tools on my system. Not that I know how to do that, but that would be a different question.
Please use small enough matrices so that we don't need to decompose them into even-smaller matrices for the computation. I want to keep it plain and simple.
You can skip error checking if you like, for brevity.
Don't bother with compilation/linking instrumentation - just the plain program or program-snippet please.
Please use C++ or C as the programming language (for the CPU-side code at least) - unless that's impossible or very difficult.
If it matters - assume we're on GNU/Linux, not Windows


Wasn't this paper published only last week? Maybe would be faster to ask Intel support directly.

PyTorch is general enough. You don't need any of those fancy CNNs. You can use it as a matrix calculator just fine.

@n.m.couldbeanAI: I don't want to write a matrix calculator. I want to do other things which also involve multiplying matrices.

@pptaszni: I was not aware of that; but, skimming it, it doesn't seem to explain how to write a program such as the one I asked for.

Of course you don't want to write a matrix calculator. PyTorch is a matrix calculator. You can use it to write your own thing.

@n.m.couldbeanAI: I haven't said anything about what "my own thing" is, how can you know I can use PyTorch for it?
